# Decoding excel file gone wrong

Tags: java, excel, decode, encode

Hello I have a REST API in which I am uploading `.xls` files. Using the debugger I can see that the excel file is getting encoded correctly.

**Code:**

```
String[] tokensVal = request.getContent().split(delimiters);
String fileContentEncoded = tokensVal[tokensVal.length-1];
```

**Result:**

```
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAbOCctygEAAIsHAAATAM4BW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiygEooAACAAAA...KxVy27bMBC8F+g/CLwWFp0eiiCwnEPSHNMAST6AIdcSYb7ApR3777uUIqM2FDWGfNF7Z3ZmH1rc7qwpthBRe1exq3LOCnDSK+3qir2+PMyuWYFJ...
```

When I am trying to decode the file with `UTF-8` charset I can see that something is going wrong.

**Code:**

```
InputStream fileContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(fileContentEncoded), UTF_8).getBytes(UTF_8));
```

**Result:**

```
PK!8'-[Content_Types].xml (Un0? CI>!aﻔ"65|{gvfZ)Q{Wr
p+ꊽ<̮YI8%wP= ]~xVI)p+YhEX Z翸.K1rq+1]&oڱ.SUL`[NHf~K%Ba)C!%rWpjs)I(,w'$'݂(bTu=@A"<OZJ^Rd[5ltq=yqҮ)Ю{    鞢ȩ֓<
```

Is anyone who faced this problem before?

Comment: I think you are receiving an XLS file and trying to treat it as a CSV file. XLS is not CSV - more like an XML-type format.

Comment: Hello @JohnXF and thanks for your reply. Do you have a solution in mind?

Comment: The solution is up to you. If you will be passed an XLS file then you need to find something to parse XLS. If you can reformat your XLS as a CSV file then your code may work. But you cannot receive an XLS file and expect to parse it like a CSV file as they are different things. If you look at XLS and CSV files in a text editor you will see the problem.

Comment: Use apache POI for interacting with a excel sheet.